# “Unable to connect to SQL Server database” - ASP.NET configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Trying to learn how roles work in ASP.NET.

I've made an empty website an created a database to it with nothing in it.

Here's the connection string:

```
   <add name="connString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
        AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\ RolesTutorial\App_Data\base.mdf';
       Integrated Security=True;
       Connect Timeout=30" />
```

I've installed SQL Express 2012.

What else can I try?

Comment: Your question misleads.! What is your Query here??

Comment: What do you want to try?

Answer (score 1):

Else u can try [entity framework.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs) It's modern and useful method. or if u prefer video tutorials here's a [good one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrr66APUwBk)

Answer (score -1):

You're not doing anything with SQL Express there, your connection string points to localdb, use management study to create a database, remove the "attachdbfilename" and change your datasource to point to SQL Express (local)\SQLExpress

Comment: Attaching database files is a feature of SQL Server.

Comment: I know, but here he's explicitely using LocalDB (NOT raw sql express) so since he mentioned he installed SQL Express 2012 i assume LocalDB version isn't what he wants.